# Ubuntu doesn't turn off

Tags: unity, shutdown

I'm new to this system, so I been using Ubuntu 16.04 TLS 64 bits a few days.

First, I did a fresh install of Windows 10 but I have the "black screen" issue on booting after the grub, I had to make a new installation but with the "apci=off" mode I think.

Then I could boot normally, but now I can't completely turn off the PC because when I click on Shutdown the desktop shut down but it keeps on Ubuntu Logo... to turn off I have to press the power button on the laptop and then shut down instantly.

I think it's not a driver issue because I have selected the non-restricted drivers for use.

When I press the Escape key the last line it's something like "Restart Held".

Comment: What happens is that system goes into halt mode. All processes stop but power must be disconnected manually. I don't know of manual fixes but i can make a workaround script. Would you like that as a possible solution ?

Comment: @Serg I tried changing removing the acpi instruction from the grub and the battery icon appears (I din't realize that before was hidden) and then i could shutdown normally but then again i have the black screen issue at boot. When I put again to acpi=off I can't turn off and the battery icon disappears.

Comment: Does it shutdown alright if you enter `sudo shutdown -P now` in command line ?

Comment: No, it keeps on `[216.996482] Reboot: System Halted`, I think that have something related to the acpi settings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an ASUS X540S.

I can turn off the computer with:

```
shutdown -h now
```

I confirm that this solution only works sometimes.

Comment: Well, in my case doesn't shutdown.